# How to add a MVC Dropdownfor list<string>

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, dropdownlistfor

I am trying to add a Dropdownlistfor to my MVC Project with no luck.
I would like to display a list of customers.
I would like the customers displayed and the ID selected.

I am struggling with casting my list into the selectListItems, Could someone please help me out with this.

Controller

```
public ActionResult createNewUser()
{

    List<string> Customers = DBH.CustomerBranchGetAll();

    var Model = new UserModel
    {
       Customers = Customers
    };

    return View(Model);

}
```

Model

```
public class UserModel
{

   public int CustomerId { get; set; }
   public List<string> Customers { get; set; }
   public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> SelectCustomers
   {
      get { return new SelectList(Customers, "Id", "Name"); }
   }
}
```

View

```
<div class="editor-label">
    @Html.Label("Choose Your Customer name")
</div>
<div class="editor-field">
    @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.CustomerId, Model.SelectCustomers)
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Customers)
</div>
```

Comment: Use

`public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> SelectCustomers
   {
      get { return new SelectList(Customers, Customers.Id, Customers.Name); }
   }`

Comment: @Pomster, where are you getting error

Comment: Tell me I am wrong, but as far as I know, the Type `string` has no Properties called `Id` and `Name`

Comment: Why does  `DBH.CustomerBranchGetAll();` return a list of string (and not a list of Customers / something with an Id and a Name) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Read [**SelectList**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.selectlist%28v=vs.118%29.aspx)

Your `Customers` is not an object which contains `Id & Name` properties. In your code it is just a list of string.`List<string> Customers`

You need to define an class with Name and Id properties and make use of it

```
public class Customer{
 public string Name{get;set;}
 public int Id {get;set;}
}
```

Then prepare a customer object with Id and Name property assigned

```
List<Customers> customers = DBH.CustomerBranchGetAll(); 
var Model = new UserModel
{
   Customers = customers
};
```

In View

```
  @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.CustomerId, 
                        new SelectList(Model.Customers,"Id","Name"))
```

Answer (score 1):

`SelectList` has a constructor that takes an `IEnumerable`.. so you just need to do this:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.CustomerId, new SelectList(Model.Customers))
```

You can remove the `SelectCustomers` property entirely.

Comment: Correct. I bypassed the problem. This will compile for the OP though. OP has clearly followed a tutorial.